# Apply columnary condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query which looks like

```
SELECT distinct
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 0) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_0,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 1) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_1,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 2) THEN 'True'
         ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_2,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 3) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_3,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 4) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_4,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 5) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_5,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 6) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_6
FROM
    slots
WHERE
    tl_id = 1
group by dow
```

its returning data  like

| DOW_0 | DOW_1 | DOW_2 | DOW_3 | DOW_4 | DOW_5 | DOW_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | False | False | False | True | False | True |
| False | True | False | False | True | False | True |
| False | False | True | False | True | False | True |
| False | False | False | False | True | True | True |

I want result in such a way if DOW_0 has any true value than return as true else false simillarly for other column as well. Below showing the desired output

| DOW_0 | DOW_1 | DOW_2 | DOW_3 | DOW_4 | DOW_5 | DOW_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False | True | True | False | True | True | True |

Comment: Only tag with the database you are using.  I removed the Oracle tag because the question explicitly mentions MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just define the current query as subquery and add aggregate on select columns.

Note: i modified 'True' with 1 and 'False' with 0

Note2: I think you dont need to use Distinct in your query. But i left it not to change your original sql. Please consider / test to do without it.

İF YOU want to see True and False as output, simply you can change it like :

```
max(DOW_0) --> case when max(DOW_0) < 1 then  'False' else 'True' end
```

---

```
    select max(DOW_0) as DOW_0 , max(DOW_1) as DOW_1 ,max(DOW_2) as DOW_2 ,max(DOW_3) as DOW_3 ,max(DOW_4) as DOW_4 ,max(DOW_5) as DOW_5 ,max(DOW_6) as DOW_6
from 
(
SELECT distinct
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 0) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) AS DOW_0,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 1) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) AS DOW_1,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 2) THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END) AS DOW_2,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 3) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) AS DOW_3,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 4) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) AS DOW_4,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 5) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) AS DOW_5,
    (CASE WHEN (dow = 6) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) AS DOW_6
FROM
    slots
WHERE
    tl_id = 1
    group by dow  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN dow = 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_0,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dow = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dow = 2 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dow = 3 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dow = 4 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dow = 5 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_5,
       MAX(CASE WHEN dow = 6 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_6
FROM slots
WHERE tl_id = 1
GROUP BY tl_id;
```

This aggregates by `tl_id` so you can get multiple ids in separate rows, if you want.

This works because `'TRUE' >` 'False'`.  I would suggest, however, using boolean flags instead:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN dow = 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_0,
       MAX( dow = 1 ) AS DOW_1,
       MAX( dow = 2 ) AS DOW_2,
       MAX( dow = 3 ) AS DOW_3,
       MAX( dow = 4 ) AS DOW_4,
       MAX( dow = 5 ) AS DOW_5,
       MAX( dow = 6 ) AS DOW_6
FROM slots
WHERE tl_id = 1
GROUP BY tl_id;
```

Comment: It will not work as it will return all rows all time..I jut want single row..so my answer mentioned above will work perfectly..Thanks

Comment: @AnshulVerma . . . Huh?  This returns one row.  It might return zero rows if `tl_id = 1` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using aggregation seems to be the best solution

However, I create a solution without `group by`

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM slots WHERE tl_id = 1 and (dow = 0)) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_0,
    (CASE WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM slots WHERE tl_id = 1 and (dow = 1)) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_1,
    (CASE WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM slots WHERE tl_id = 1 and (dow = 2)) THEN 'True'
         ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_2,
    (CASE WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM slots WHERE tl_id = 1 and (dow = 3)) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_3,
    (CASE WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM slots WHERE tl_id = 1 and (dow = 4)) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_4,
    (CASE WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM slots WHERE tl_id = 1 and (dow = 5)) THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_5,
    (CASE WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM slots WHERE tl_id = 1 and (dow = 6))THEN 'True'
          ELSE 'False' END) AS DOW_6
```

Comment: I'm sorry, indeed my solution is for mssql TS-SQL

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer- just need to apply max for each field in order to get the Max value which would be 0/1

```
SELECT 
    MAX(dow.DOW_0),
    MAX(dow.DOW_1),
    MAX(dow.DOW_2),
    MAX(dow.DOW_3),
    MAX(dow.DOW_4),
    MAX(dow.DOW_5),
    MAX(dow.DOW_6)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        (CASE
                WHEN (dow = 0) THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END) AS DOW_0,
            (CASE
                WHEN (dow = 1) THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END) AS DOW_1,
            (CASE
                WHEN (dow = 2) THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END) AS DOW_2,
            (CASE
                WHEN (dow = 3) THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END) AS DOW_3,
            (CASE
                WHEN (dow = 4) THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END) AS DOW_4,
            (CASE
                WHEN (dow = 5) THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END) AS DOW_5,
            (CASE
                WHEN (dow = 6) THEN 'True'
                ELSE 'False'
            END) AS DOW_6
    FROM
        slots
    WHERE
        tl_id = 1
    GROUP BY dow) dow
```

Comment: Grouping by `dow` explicitly puts each dow on a different row.  Just don't use `GROUP BY` at all, and you'll get one row.  Then you can put `MAX()` around each `CASE` expression.  The approach here creates additional processing cost needlessly.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.